# Transfer of Databound Datagridview Row To Another Datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, datatable

I have a two datagridview as

datagridview1

datagridview2

datagridview1 has a checkbox columns which check the rowindex and transfer the same row to another datagridview2

datagridview1 is a databound control and having columns as below:

checkbox Column,Name and Amount

where as datagridview2 also having same column accept checkbox column.

I wants to transfer data of datagridview1.selected rows to another datagridview2 by click on checkbox column.

How to do?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by handling CellContentClick event of DataGridView. Then you check if check box column was clicked, get current row and import it into another DataGridView. Here is what I mean:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == myCheckBoxColumnName.Index) {
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                string name = row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
                string amount = row.Cells["Amount"].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add(name, amount);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think You are not read my question well. The datagridview1 is databound control and your code throw complie error like "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."

Comment: @mahesh Then transfer them to your data source. Just replace the last line. I gave you the idea of getting values from checked row... You only need to add those values to your data source.